# Unable to pass a value from a function to a text box

Tags: javascript

I am very new to JavaScript and I need some help. I am trying to pass a value from a function within the `<head>` of my HTML document, so that it'll run once the page loads, and I am unable to figure out how to pass a value from the function to a text box within a form in the `<body>` of the document.

```
alert ('Starting now');
function calc(){
    const FEES=14.5;
    const DUES=5;
    var cFees;
    var lDues; 
    cFees=FEES * 16;
    lDues=DUES * 16;
    document.getElementById("league");
    }

alert('Finished');
```

I am unable to understand what I am suppose to do in order to pass along the value of `cFees` to a text box with the id of "league". The alerts are there to indicate that it is actually starting/ending properly.

EDIT: here is the code that I want to pass the values to

```
<form>
</div> 
<div id="righta">
<input type="text" name="league"  id="league" readonly />League Dues
<br />
<input type="text" name="fee"  id="fee" readonly />Golf Course Fees
<br />
<input type="text" name="total"  id="total" readonly />Total for the Season
</div> 
</form>
```

Comment: you've defined a function called `calc` that doesn't accept any parameters. You need to call that function for it's internal code to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set its value property:

```
document.getElementById('league').value = cFees;
```

If you were passing it to an HTML element, you may wish to use innerHTML instead...

e.g. `<div id="divTest"></div>`

```
document.getElementById('divTest').innerHTML = cFees;
```

If you wish it to run when the page loads, then add an event listener to the window...

```
window.addEventListener(
    'load',
    function() {
        document.getElementById('league').value = cFees;
    },
    false);
```

**FULL CODE EXAMPLE**

Here's a full HTML example showing the fields being updated accordingly as per the calc() function. I've set this to update on the load of the window, but you could set it via some other event, if you wish.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script>
            function calc() {
                const FEES = 14.5;
                const DUES = 5;
                var cFees = FEES * 16;
                var lDues = DUES * 16;
                document.getElementById('txtFees').value = cFees.toFixed(2);
                document.getElementById('txtDues').value = lDues.toFixed(2);
            }

            window.addEventListener('load', calc, false);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="txtFees" type="text" value="" readonly>
        <input id="txtDues" type="text" value="" readonly>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it still isn't working properly. The page still loads without any of the fields filled in.

Comment: You'll need to calculate the value of cFees before setting it here, of course. And you'll need to add similar lines for each field that you wish to have filled with data. But you can do that yourself. Or, if you clarify your requirements, then I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Updated my answer to better suit your requirements :)

Comment: Thank you, that did work. Just curious, is there a way to do it without the window.addEventListener?

Comment: Several ways. You can call calc() at any point you wish. You could add it to the onclick event of a button, the onsubmit of a form, etc.

Comment: Thank you again, you have helped me out a lot with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function() {
  //body of your func
  document.getElementById("league"). value = cFees;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function cannot edit html from the head. If it must be in the head, you need to make an event listener.

```
window.addEventListener( 'load', function() { calc(); }, false);
```